# revert to original position in jquery ui, after drop

Tags: jquery, html

I want to revert my draggable to original position after removing from droppable by dragging. but i need this **using plugin** can anyone suggest me how to do it just by adding parameter in my drag initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified jquery-ui plugin for this functionality
here is [GitHub url](https://github.com/sirajpathan/jquery_drag)

you just need to add below code

```
$('.drag').draggable({
revert: 'invalid',
revertToOgPos: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, You need help
below is your answer :

```
$(".drag").draggable({
            revert: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0
                };

                return !event;
            }
        });
```